How to use CSS round() in SCSS, that also have round?
Someone use my CSS library in SCSS, and it gives this error, when I use round().

jquery.terminal.css:850:22": argument $number of round($number) must be a number

According to MDN round is in baseline https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/round
So how I'm supposed to make a CSS library that use round when users use SCSS?
EDIT: this is the code I use in my library:
--terminal-line: calc(var(--size, 1) * (16px / var(--pixel-density, 1)) + 1px / var(--pixel-density, 1));

line-height: round(var(--terminal-line, 1em));


How are you using round? what are the contents of $number? Have you read the documentation on Legacy Global Functions?

@admcfajn Update the question.

What does --terminal-line equal? Can you change line-height: round(var(--terminal-line, 1em)) to line-height: round(var(--terminal-line))? Or style="--terminal-line: 'n'" to style="--terminal-line: n"?

@admcfajn it doesn't matter what is the value of --terminal-line that error is happening because SCSS need number from SCSS and got a string var(...). But I've updated the question with the value of that variable.

Your example works fine on the Sass playground. You may be using an older version of Sass, in which case updating will fix this issue. Support for round() and other CSS Values and Units 4 calculation functions were added in Dart Sass 1.67.0.

You can escape the SASS compilation using {''} (https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation/#quoted-strings)
line-height: #{'round(var(--terminal-line, 1em))'};


It will not work, because this is CSS library used by someone that use SCSS. I can't put this into CSS code. I would need to write my library as SCSS just to use round. Which is silly.

According to SASS documentation, SASS overrides the default round() CSS function to be a SASS round() function that accepts $number and returns the closest whole number to $number. The default CSS function accepts 1 to 3 parameters though, which is likely the problem you are encountering. Since your code should is CSS, it shouldn't be interpreted as SCSS so I'm confused as to why that is the case.
What you should do is have your CSS library be a separate file that users can import into their SCSS file (via an @import declaration). See SO question 7111610 answer by tftd which explains how someone might do that if they are facing problems with the @import declaration, but as the question states, as of December 2014 the issue that prevented importing CSS files into SCSS files has been resolved.
